# Can I make PCB panel with PCBs with defined assembly variants in Altium designer?

Tags: pcb-design, altium

I have two PCBs that make one system, each PCB have two assembly versions. I need to make PCB panel that contain one of each PCB with right selected version.

[It is possible](https://resources.altium.com/p/how-panelize-your-pcbs-lunch-altium-designer) to make PCB panel just for fabrication easy, but I don't know how to make assembly that depend on version. I can remove lines of elements that in version is not about to be placed in pick-and-place file, but this could be done in some othe proper way, right?

Comment: This is a question for your assembly vendor.

Comment: I don't think this can be controlled from Altium. I mean, altium has some support for variants, but that support is at the schematic level. I don't think you can map a variant to a specific instance on a panel with multiple PCB's.

Answer (score 0):

This isn’t a layout thing, it’s a schematic and Bill of Material (BOM) issue.

You can have variants of the schematic that differ in BOM configuration yet refer to the same PCB artwork. The PCB itself should be common to all the BOM variants. Just make sure you make no connection or footprint changes that would affect the net list.

Typically what you do is indicate no-load components on the variants with some kind of notation such as ‘DNI’ (do not install) appended to the device name. You then post-process your generated BOM to prune away the unloaded parts.

It’s also possible to do no-load as an attribute of its own, but this is less clear on the schematic and requires that you pick up that attribute when you make the BOM. This is actually more work than using a modified device name.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way from an assembly house point of view, is this:

1. Have 2 separate part numbers, one for each top level assembly.
2. Generate 2 different BOMs, again, one for each assembly. Don't do a single BOM with 2 variants and instructions.
3. Some assembly houses can't handle DNI/DNP properly, so simply remove these parts from the BOM. This is especially relevant for low cost assembly houses, they don't want to invest extra engineering effort.
4. The PCB (bare board) should have its own part number in the BOM.